# conditional probability which their condition have $XOR and Z=X+Y$

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent binary random variable with the same alphabet {$0,1$},ie,$Pr(0)=Pr(1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Define $I(X;Y|Z)=H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)$

$1.$Let $Z=X+Y$,Find $I(X;Y|Z)$

$2.$Let $Z=X ⊕Y$, Find $I(X;Y|Z)$. ⊕ means XOR operation

For these two questions,i don't know how to find their probability,can anyone teach me

By the way, i know the $I$(information) and $H$(entropy) are not the probability,$Pr(X;Y|Z)$,but i need the probability before calculating them

Comment: So you want the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$? $Z$ can be $0,1$ or $2.$ Conditional on $Z=0,$ $(X,Y) = (0,0)$ with probability one. Conditional on $Z=2,$ $(X,Y)=(1,1)$ with probability one. And conditional on $Z=1,$ $(X,Y) = (1,0)$ with probability $1/2$ and $(X,Y) = (0,1)$ with probability $1/2.$

Comment: oh!you misunderstand something,that 2 is the question two.And in fact, i want the  joint distribution of X given  Y and Z to calculate the  I(X;Y|Z)

Comment: Given $Y$ and $Z$, the value of $X$ is certain in both parts 1 and 2

Comment: @Henry I just think that is H(X|Y,Z)=H(X|Z)? Because  P(X|Y,Z) should me the sum of Pr(X=x) given that Y=y and Z=z

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the probabilities.  These are:

```
X    Y   X+Y  X⊕Y  Prob
0    0    0    0    1/4 
0    1    1    1    1/4
1    0    1    1    1/4
1    1    2    0    1/4
```

For $\mathbb P(X=x \mid Z=z)$, in Part 1 you have, as spaceisdarkgreen says,

- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=0)=1$, $\,\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=0)=0$,
- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=1)=\frac12$, $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=1)=\frac12$,
- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=2)=0$, $\,\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X+Y=1)=1$

In Part 2 you have

- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X⊕Y=0)=\frac12$, $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X⊕Y=0)=\frac12$,
- $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X⊕Y=1)=\frac12$, $\mathbb P(X=1 \mid X⊕Y=1)=\frac12$

Given both $Y$ and $Z$, the value of $X$ is certain in both parts 1 and 2, since in part 1 you have $X=Z-Y$ while in part 2 you have $X=Z⊕Y$

Comment: Why is the $P(X=0|X+Y=0)=1$,not $\frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: @ShineSun Because the only case where $X+Y=0$ is the top row of the table.  You need to calculate the conditional probability $\mathbb P(X=0 \mid X+Y=0)= \dfrac{\mathbb P(X=0 , X+Y=0)}{\mathbb P(X+Y=0)} =\dfrac{1/4}{1/4}=1$

Comment: get it! can i ask how to calculate the P(X|Y,Z) according to your table?because i think P(X|Y,Z) may be equal to P(X,Z)